# PngComponents for Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need this [PngComponents](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26127) pack for D7. I need only TPngImageList. 
If i try to compile this pack (pas files) in D7, i get many errors:

```
unknown compiler directive {$Pointermath}
invalid operation for "PByte(ptr1) - PByte(ptr2)"
unknown feature "class var"
unknown ft "class function"
etc
```

Does some ready pack exist for D7? Or only TPngImageList to use in SpTBX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Delphi 7 version of the component can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/cubicexplorer/downloads/detail?name=PngComponents.zip&can=2&q=

For what it is worth, I just did a simple [web search](http://www.google.com/search?q=PngComponents%20%22delphi%207%22) to find that link. Learning how to use web search is one of the most important skills in development.